# Change Revision Number in Subversion, even if the File not change in the commit

Tags: svn, version-control

I use $Rev:$ in a file to have the revision number, the problem is that the file does not change a lot so the number is not automatically updated. Any help in how to do this?

Comment: This is a FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=subversion+revision+number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$Rev$ won't work the way you expect it.

If you're using command-line subversion you have [svnversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.ref.svnversion.re.html) that outputs the latest revision.

With tortoisesvn, it's http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-subwcrev.html

Anyway, you should update your build script, so that it merges automatically the lastest 
revision number.

Comment: what I did is that I use subwcrev with a tmp file with the revision number. Then I change my beforeBuild action in vs2008 to call the exe and now its working.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using this for a build/version number in a file, look into the svnrev or WCSubRev tools to create the information you need.