# Can I set an environment variable with the SVN revision number of a project?

Tags: svn, batch-file, environment-variables

I am trying to get the revision number of a project and save it into a variable. I know I can get the revision number by svnversion command but I'm not sure how I can store it. I am using regular windows command prompt. Basically I'm trying to do something like :
set svnVersion= %svnversion% but I'm not sure how??

Comment: Do you really need to do it in a batch file? If it's for a project build system then there might be easier ways to do it, for example in combination with ant in the Java world.

Comment: I strongly recommend switching to any unix/linux family OS if you want to do something with command-line for anything.

Answer (score 7):

To set the output of variable to the output of svnversion in a batch file, you have to do this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('svnversion') do @set myvar=%%a

echo %myvar%
```

---

Different approach: If you have TortoiseSVN you can also use **SubWCRev.exe**. See 
[get the project revision number into my project?](http://tortoisesvn.net/node/18) or [Automatic SVN Revision Numbering in ASP.Net MVC](http://www.fatlemon.co.uk/2008/12/automatic-svn-revision-numbering-in-aspnet-mvc/)

Comment: In a batch file you'd have to double the % signs for the 'for' variable.

Comment: actually I think single % is the right choice. At least that's how it works on my system

Answer (score 3):

If you need this from a remote repository (as in not checked out localy) you can do this

```
for /f "delims=: tokens=1,2" %%a in ('svn info %SVN_REPO_URL%') do (
  if "%%a"=="Revision" (
    set /a RELEASE_REVISION=%%b
  )
)
```

I use this in my release process to grab the revision number from a tag.

Answer (score 2):

In bash (via Cygwin):

```
svn info | grep -i "Revision" | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

You can then use that in a bash shell script to store the value in a variable.

Comment: I'm not sure most people run bash as their "regular windows command prompt" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The "svn info" subcommand will tell you the revision number in your working copy.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
svn version > ver.txt
set /p ver= < ver.txt
del ver.txt
echo %ver%
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this help: [Change Revision Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562087/change-revision-number-in-subversion-even-if-the-file-not-change-in-the-commit)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative that uses a pipe to findstr to get a single line:

```
FOR /F "tokens=2" %%G IN ('svn info ^| findstr /B Revision:') DO SET SVN_REVISION=%%G
echo SVN_REVISION: %SVN_REVISION%

FOR /F "tokens=2" %%G IN ('svn info ^| findstr /B URL:') DO SET SVN_URL=%%G
echo SVN_URL: %SVN_URL%
```